# Forms authentication asp.net mvc not authenticating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

When I try to login, the FormsAuthentication is not working. It successfully logs in and the sessions are saved. After it redirects me to the `Index` view, the value for `@FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled` is false.

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
        {
            if (IsValid(user.Username, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
                Session["Username"] = user.Username;
                Session["IP"] = user.IPAddress;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Details are wrong!");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Was your template originally using asp.net identity?  If so, it removes the FormsAuthenticationModule, look for this in your web.config and take it out.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name/version of the browser you are using?

may be the following link will be useful if you are using IE 11
https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/aspnet-40-forms-authentication-issues-with-ie11/

Answer (score 0):

The authentication mode in web.config needs to be "Forms" for the property `FormsAuthentication.Enabled` to return true. Below is the decompiled code from dotpeek.

```
public static bool IsEnabled
{
  get
  {
    return AuthenticationConfig.Mode == AuthenticationMode.Forms;
  }
}
```